# xgboost giving inf or nan error, but no infinite values in training data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

It seems that when I am trying to run xgboost, that I am being accosted to check the data values, however i do not have any infinite or nan values. I have been using this code for years, and it seems that recently with one of the package updates this started occurring. Has anyone else witnessed this or know the cause?

Below is showing me evaluating the input data, and the error that occurs when processing my numpy matrices.

```
np.isnan(x_train).any()
Out[72]: False

np.isnan(y_train).any()
Out[73]: False

min(x_train.flatten())
Out[58]: -1.8606612930273785e+79

max(x_train.flatten())
Out[59]: 1.828733011430676e+79
```

File "", line 1, in 
training.train_model(x_train,y_train)

File "C:\Users\kinsm\Dropbox (Personal)\Other\Python\finance\training.py", line 63, in train_model
model = model.fit(x, y)

File "C:\Users\kinsm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 436, in inner_f
return f(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\kinsm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 1158, in fit
train_dmatrix, evals = _wrap_evaluation_matrices(

File "C:\Users\kinsm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 236, in _wrap_evaluation_matrices
train_dmatrix = create_dmatrix(

File "C:\Users\kinsm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 1172, in 
create_dmatrix=lambda **kwargs: DMatrix(nthread=self.n_jobs, **kwargs),

File "C:\Users\kinsm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 436, in inner_f
return f(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\kinsm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 541, in **init**
handle, feature_names, feature_types = dispatch_data_backend(

File "C:\Users\kinsm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py", line 564, in dispatch_data_backend
return _from_numpy_array(data, missing, threads, feature_names,

File "C:\Users\kinsm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py", line 163, in _from_numpy_array
_check_call(_LIB.XGDMatrixCreateFromMat_omp(

File "C:\Users\kinsm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 210, in _check_call
raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))

XGBoostError: [10:15:32] C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.4.0/src/data/data.cc:945: Check failed: valid: Input data contains `inf` or `nan`